# What is the beam width of the antenna of Voyager 2?

Tags: voyager

There is a communication pause with Voyager 2 since July 21, the antenna points 2 degrees away from Earth. A series of planned commands sent to NASA’s Voyager 2 inadvertently changed the antenna alignment.

Source [Mission Update: Voyager 2 Communications Pause](https://blogs.nasa.gov/sunspot/2023/07/28/mission-update-voyager-2-communications-pause/)

How large is the beam width compared to the 2 degrees miss-alignment?

Comment: https://descanso.jpl.nasa.gov/DPSummary/Descanso4--Voyager_new.pdf.  0.5°.  Just providing the link for those who want to make it a full answer

Comment: FWIW, from Voyager 2's perspective, the Earth's orbit is currently around 1° wide. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPzYx.png The time step in that plot is 3 days, with 60 days between numeric labels.

Answer (score 10):

According to Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_antenna the half-power beam width for a 3.7m diameter antennae (like Voyager 2) with X-band transmission at 3.6cm would be  0.60 degrees.

Voyager 2 also has S-band communications at 13cm which would have a half-power beam width of 2.5 degrees using the same parabolic reflector.

Comment: But is S-band downlink still possible over the huge distance from Voyager 2 to Earth? Antenna gain 36 dB for S-band  is much smaller than 48 dB for X-band. S-band seems to be used only after launch but not nowadays.

Comment: Sounds like a new question. @Roger Wood is very knowledgeable on Voyager communications.

Comment: Doesn't Voyager only use S-band for uplink? X-Band is for downlink and irrelevant here, because earth needs to upload the corrected navigation commands, not download anything.